# How can I add an SSH key to Gitlab through a bash executable?

Tags: command-line, bash, ssh, git, gitlab

I am creating a bash executable, which creates an SSH key, and uploads it to a user's Gitlab account. I am aware of how to create the SSH key via the bash executable:

```
ssh-keygen -o -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

and I also know how to retrieve from it, however I don't know how to upload it to a user's Gitlab account.

I have found multiple documentations for uploading a user's SSH to Git**hub** however not Gitlab (I assume mostly similar...?). So I would use this for Git**hub**

```
curl -u "USERNAME:PASSWORD" --data "{\"title\": \"TITLE\", \"key\": \"$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub)\"}" https://api.github.com/user/keys
```

and I would make `USERNAME`, `PASSWORD`, and `TITLE` input fields for the user to customize.

I want to say that it would be as simple for Gitlab (I found `POST /users/:id/keys` on [their API site](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/users.html#add-ssh-key), but don't know how to implement it as a `curl` command), but I don't know how closely related Gitlab and Github are.

Comment: I am not sure this is related to Ubuntu.

Comment: @user68186 is it not? Do you suggest another place for me to ask this? Like maybe Unix & Linux?

Comment: @a.mosallaei It’s simple: Do you use Ubuntu? If yes, your question is clearly about [using and administering](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) it and thus on-topic. If you however use another distribution or an unsupported release, [unix.se] is the place to ask.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first problem you need to solve when using the Gitlab REST API is the authentification, nicely explained in [the docs here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/#authentication). I use a personal access token in this post which creation is explained [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html#creating-a-personal-access-token), but for you with a script authenticating as a specific user an [Impersonation token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/#impersonation-tokens) (see [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/users.html#create-an-impersonation-token) for the creation) may be better suited.

To [add an ssh key](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/users.html#add-ssh-key) I need:

```
POST /user/keys
```

To send data (and subsequently use the POST method) `curl` provides the `-d` option, required fields are `title` and `key`. As the default header is `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` but the API expects `json` I have to specify that using the `-H` option:

```
$ curl -d '{"title":"test key","key":"'"$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub)"'"}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' https://gitlab.com/api/v4/user/keys?private_token=<my_access_token>
{"id":3889765,"title":"test key","key":"ssh-rsa <my_ssh_key>","created_at":"2019-08-01T21:26:40.952Z"}
```

Now to test the change I just [list my ssh keys](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/users.html#list-ssh-keys). The docs say I have to use `GET /user/keys`, as GET is `curl`’s default method I just do:

```
$ curl https://gitlab.com/api/v4/user/keys?private_token=<my_access_token>
[{"id":3889765,"title":"test key","key":"ssh-rsa <my_ssh_key>","created_at":"2019-08-01T21:26:40.952Z"}]
```

I did this just for testing, so I’m going to [delete the key](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/users.html#delete-ssh-key-for-current-user) with `DELETE /user/keys/:key_id` – note that `:key_id` needs to be substituted by the id of the key to delete:

```
$ curl -X DELETE https://gitlab.com/api/v4/user/keys/3889765?private_token=<my_access_token>
```

Here’s [a nice article about `curl` and the common REST methods](https://www.baeldung.com/curl-rest).

Comment: this is a very in-depth answer, and I really appreciate it. Just a clarifying question, `curl -d '{"title":"test key","key":"'"$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub)"'"}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' https://gitlab.com/api/v4/user/keys?private_token=<my_access_token>` this code sends the SSH key to the user's account? I have to have some code to access a user's account, correct? Like some code that takes input of user's username and password. I believe it is written in the API how to receive this data, but if you could clarify for me, I would be more than grateful.

Comment: @a.mosallaei No, with an access token like I used here (see first paragraph) you don’t need this information, just the correct token. I didn’t find a way to authenticate with username and password with the API, which may very well be by design.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I do appreciate it though

Comment: @a.mosallaei You’re welcome! Do I correctly read between the lines that you actually want to write a script that *asks* the user for the gitlab credentials and then authenticates with *them*? If yes I think posting that as a [new question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) is the right thing to do.

Comment: Yes :/. honestly it is easier for me and in the end more reliable for the work I do. I will definitely post it as a new question though. Thanks!

Comment: here's the [new question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1162782/how-to-authenticate-with-a-users-gitlab-username-and-password-through-a-bash-ex). Thank you for all the help once again!!